# mode variant in org-mode code-block

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting

I would like to add a quote from an rpm-spec file fragment in one of my org-mode documentation, e.g.:

```
#+begin_src rpm-spec
  Name: foo
  Version: 1.0.0
  BuildRequires: bar

  %description
  foo the bar with some baz
#+end_src
```

My issue is that `rpm-spec` file is not a mode per-se, but a variant of `shell-script` mode. When I am visiting my `foo.spec` file, I see it using the `Shell-script[rpm]` mode, but I don't know how to specify this sub-mode in an org-mode code-block.  The `rpm-spec` in the example above is just a place holder, and I was not able to find any combination that will highlight it properly.

So my question: **Is there a way to specify for an org-mode code-block a specific mode variant e.g. `Shell-script[rpm]` of a code fragment, and if so how?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
(add-to-list 'org-babel-load-languages '(rpm-spec . t) t)
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("rpm-spec" . shell-script))
```

I don't know if it makes sense to execute those blocks, or what that would mean, but if it does, just define this function, and do something with the body of the code and the src-block info that is provided.

```
(defun org-babel-execute:rpm-spec (body info)
  (message "%S\n\n%S" body info))
```